# durandaljs - how to query a DOM element from a widget after ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, durandal

I want to query a element in a durandaljs widget, when it's ready.
If i use the selector directly in the data-binding, the element will not be found:

html (no attached view):

```
<button id="myButton"></button>
<div data-bind="widget: { kind: 'myWidget', options: { btn: $('#myButton') } }"></div>
```

controller.js:

```
define(function (require) {
    var ctor = function (element, settings) {
        var btn = settings.options.btn;
        // btn = $('#myButton'); // this will work, but i'm not sure if the DOM is
                                 // currently ready in the constructor
        btn.on("click", function () {
           console.log("I want to be fired");
        });
    };

    return ctor;
});
```

Whats the best way to query a DOM element from a durandal widget at start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the html fragment belongs to so there are two slightly different answers.

First I'd suggest that you don't pass in the `btn`as jQuery object (`{btn: $('myButton')}`) , when you're not sure that it already exists. It's probably better to pass in a selector `{btn: '#myButton'}` and let the widget figure out how to deal with it.

Does your widget have its own view.html and the button is defined inside? If that's the case than you should take a look at the `viewAttached` callback.

```
var ctor = function (element, settings) {
    this.btn = settings.options.btn;
};

ctor.prototype.viewAttached = function (view){
   var btn = $(this.btn, view);
   if ( btn.length > 0 ) {
       btn.on("click", function () {
       console.log("I want to be fired");
    });

   }

}
```

If your widget doesn't have its own view.html than you should let the widget know by adding a view property to the settings object with a value of false.

Here's the paragraph from http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Widget/ that explains that.

> Note: In some cases, your widget may not actually need a view. Perhaps it's just adding some jQuery behavior or applying an existing jQuery plugin to a dom element. To tell Durandal that there is no view to load and bind, add a view property to the settings object with a value of false inside your widget's constructor.

In that instance however you can only access elements that are already in the DOM when the widget is instantiated e.g.

```
var ctor = function (element, settings) {
    settings.view = false;
    this.btn = $(settings.options.btn);

    if ( this.btn.length > 0 ) {
        this.btn.on("click", function () {
            console.log("I want to be fired");
        });
    }
};
```